# What is /iə/ in English?

Tags: pronunciation, phonology, phonetics, morphology

I am confusing with phonetic symbols between /iə/ and /ɪə/. I know that /ɪə/ is a diphthong vowel, combining between /ɪ/ and schwa /ə/. But what is /iə/? Is it /i:/+/ə/? How different are they pronounced?

Comment: The sound is the same (/iə/= /ɪə/). The difference has nothing to do with vowel length. /iə/ must be just a variation of the phonetic symbol /ɪə/. But, to be honest, I have never seen /iə/ in dictionaries (e.g. mere [mɪə]).

Comment: The [Wiktionary:IPA pronunciation key](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wiktionary:IPA_pronunciation_key) page doesn't mention /iə/ either. Where did you find it?

Comment: In what English words have you encountered these two sounds?

Comment: @Enguroo /iə/ is just a sequence of two different phonemes whereas /ɪə/ is a single phoneme, a single vowel with a changing trajectory.

Comment: @MrLister It does! It lists /i/ and /ə/ ;-) When you see /iə/ it's just two distinct vowels one after the other (see my post below for a better explanation).

Comment: Can anyone give an example of a word in which /iə/ is a sequence of two different phonemes please...

Comment: @Enguroo See my post below!

Comment: @Enguroo I think tchrist's examples work eg 'via', two distinct phonemes, not a diphthong

Comment: Related: https://english.stackexchange.com/q/284850 and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English-language_vowel_changes_before_historic_/r/#Mirror%E2%80%93nearer_merger

Answer (score 21):

Take, for example, the word *beer*. Here we would use the transcription /bɪə/ in Southern Standard British English (SSBE). Notice that this word has two phonemes, the consonant /b/ and the vowel /ɪə/. That vowel—often referred to as the NEAR vowel—is a single vowel.  We use two symbols to represent it because this vowel changes quality as we say it. It starts of with a KIT-like quality, [ɪ] and finishes with a schwa-like quality, [ə]. Notice that we don't treat it as two distinct vowels, but as a single unit, even though we use two symbols to represent it.

In English we also talk about the HAPPY vowel (the vowel at the end of the word *happy*). For most younger speakers this is an allophone of the FLEECE vowel which occurs in unstressed, unchecked syllables (an unchecked syllable is just a syllable with no consonant at the end of it). For other speakers this is an allophone of the KIT vowel. Because this vowel may be considered one of either /ɪ/ or /i:/ by different speakers, and because it occurs at the end of such a large number of English words, we use the convention of representing this occurrence of the vowel using a single < i > with no length marks in transcriptions of SSBE. (Whether this is more confusing than helpful, is open to some debate. John Wells remarked [in one of his blogs](http://phonetic-blog.blogspot.co.uk/2012/06/happy-again.html) that "it seemed like a good idea at the time"!).

Now, consider the verb *copy*. The normal transcription for this in SSBE would be /kɒp.i/. At the end of that transcription, we see an occurrence of /i/. Now we can add an *-er* suffix onto this verb to turn it into the noun *copier*. In speech, this suffix is realised as a single schwa, /ə/. So the transcription you'll see in many dictionaries for this word will be /ˈkɒp.i.ə/. This, for example, is the transcription given by the [*Cambridge English Dictionary*](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/copier). And also by John Wells's *Longman Pronunciation Dictionary*. Notice that, according to this transcription, there are two distinct phonemes at the end of this word /i/ and /ə/, not a single diphthong /ɪə/. This also fits neatly with the morphology of the word.

The use of /i/ to represent a vowel in positions where the FLEECE-KIT distinction, iː vs. ɪ, is neutralized is a relatively modern innovation, and fifty years ago, nearly all phoneticians were using /ɪə/ in words like *copier*. Indeed, this transcription is still used by some dictionaries.  This however, gives the rather unsatisfactory result of a morpheme being represented by half of a vowel (urgh!).

---

<sup>**Note**: The capitalised words FLEECE, KIT, HAPPY and so forth, are the keywords from John Wells's [lexical sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_set). They can be thought of as names for the vowels concerned (so FLEECE is used to refer to the phoneme /i:/ and so forth). The HAPPY vowel refers, of course, to the second vowel in the word *happy*. Wells couldn't use a one syllable word there because this vowel only occurs in unstressed, unchecked syllables—any single syllable word would inevitably be pronounced with stress in its citation form and therefore with a regular full length FLEECE vowel.</sup>

Comment: Pronunciation and perception change. Possibly the /iə/ in *copier* really was perceived as the unaccented version of the /ɪə/ diphthong in *beer* 100 years ago (or whenever they first started using that notation). It doesn't seem very likely to me, but it also doesn't seem likely that the phoneme /ɪ/ in *king* and *ink* would change to /iː/, the way it has for many Californians.

Comment: @PeterShor Yes, quite. It's not a cut and dried issue by any means.

Comment: It would be more helpful if you could illustrate these in a way that makes sense to rhotic speakers of English. Otherwise the phantom /r/ that you pretend isn't there but which we hear will drive us nuts. [We aren’t all Jonathan Ross](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ld3A3QCpXd4), you know. Consider using one of more of: *Academia, Bohemia, California, dysgraphia, egomania, fantasia, Gambia, hernia, hypoxia, intelligentsia, Julia, kalmia, loggia, media, nutria, Olympia, pneumonia, quadriplegia, regalia, stadia, taqueria, urea, Valencia, wistaria, xenophobia, yersinia, zirconia.*

Comment: @tchrist I toyed with that idea. But unless I'm mistaken, Cambridge and Wells would give /i.ə/ for all those words ... I don't think Gen Am speakers have /ɪə/ exactly. It only appeared in East-pondian Englishes when the /r/s started to drop off the ends of the words - and for that reason I can't give you a rhotic  /ɪə/!  I'm afraid my knowledge of Gen American phonology is pretty shaky at best :( However, if you want to have an edit, do feel free (though I reserve the right to roll back if we wildly disagree!)

Comment: Are you saying (or implying) that there's no explicit notation in IPA for marking when two adjacent vowels form a diphthong versus two separate vowels?

Comment: @Mitch Yes, there is, but only in narrow transcription [ ... ] not in standard phonemic transcriptions //. Same goes for affricates. That's why it's rubbish when dictionaries don't put in syllable boundaries (can't distinguish between t +  ʃ and tʃ - for example). Not the greatest ... Arguably, putting in the syllable boundaries clears a lot of it up.

Comment: @Mitch: actually, you'd probably use it in standard phonemic transcription in languages where a diphthong would regularly be confused with two adjacent vowels. But that's not the case in English if you use /ɪə/ and /iə/ for the two different cases.

Comment: @PeterShor Yes, you're right there. It depends on the language in question and the language-specific conventions used. Was just thinking about English.

Comment: @Arucasia
I would like to know more information about allophone in long vowel sound /i:/. I have learnt that in long vowel sound as in /i:/, /u:/, and all diphthongs except /ʊə/, have two allophones depending on the last consonant sound
- see and seed have the allophone /i:/
  -see is unchecked syllable  /si:/
  -seed has the voiced consonant sound /d/> /si:d/.
  -seat is /sit/ because the consonant /t/ is voiceless.
Is /i/ from seat is the same sound as the allophone of FLEECE and as the word copier, which you explained? Can I pronounce them as the same way?

Comment: @NonameKun The quality is the same for many speakers, but in terms of length I'd say the /i/ in *copier* is probably shorter (*seat* will usually be stressed even though there's pre-fortis clipping).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You help me to understand more clearly.
Could you mind if I have another question?
I saw on the Oxford dictionary; Weak vowels /i/ and /u/. (https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/about/english/pronunciation_english) It explains that /iə/ can be /jə/ as in dubious /ˈdjuːbiəs / or /ˈdjuːbjəs/.  How can /iə/ become /jə/?

Comment: @NonameKun It's probably best to think of it not as /iə/becoming /jə/ exactly, but more that these words can have two different pronunciations, one with three syllables and another with two using a /j/ as the first consonant in the last syllable.

Comment: By the HAPPY vowel, I assume you mean the *second* vowel in "happy"? That threw me for a minute. Also, the OED has /bɪ(ə)r/ for the US pronunciation of "beer"—it's more clearly a diphthong than the British vowel, but I think still qualitatively different from the vowels in /ˈkɑpiər/.

Comment: I’m American, so maybe that’s the cause, but I have absolutely no idea what you mean by “KIT vowel,” “HAPPY vowel,” or “FLEECE vowel.” Are you referring to the vowels in those words? And if so, which one in *happy*? Or are those, as all-caps might suggest, acronyms for something?

Comment: @KRyan 1006a They're the keywords from Wells's lexical sets, widely used by phoneticians etc to refer to the vowels concerned (so, they're used as names for those vowels). Those words  were chosen  because they're meant to be difficult to confuse with words with similar vowels. You can read about them [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_set) and [here](http://phonetic-blog.blogspot.co.uk/2010/02/lexical-sets.html). They're traditionally written in capitals to distinguish them from the words *kit*, *fleece* etc. ...

Comment: @1006a Kryan ... (cont)  The names HAPPY, COMMA  (and LETTER in Gen Am) are the only two syllable words, and the vowels concerned are indeed the second vowels in those words.

Comment: @KRyan 1006a I've added a postscript note. Does that make things clearer at all?

Comment: I wasn't permanently confused, just momentarily thrown out of your narrative as I pondered whether you meant the first or second vowel. I like your post-script, but you might want to specify that the HAPPY vowel only appears at the end of multi-syllable words *for UK speakers*, as most US speakers don't actually distinguish between the vowels in FLEECE and HAPPY. The OED writes them as /iː/ and /i/, respectively, for British English, but has /i/ for both for US English; so the word *bee*, for example, is /bi/ for US speakers.

Comment: @1006a: The "happy" vowel is restricted to unstressed syllables, but it can occur in medial as well as final syllables; e.g. the second syllable of *variation.*

Comment: @sumelic I can't hear any difference at all between the unstressed vowel in "happy" and the stressed vowel in "bee" (or "fleece"), unless it is perhaps one of duration. (Or did you mean to correct my paraphrase of the postscript? Yes, that was sloppy.)

Comment: @1006a: Right, I was just trying to clarify the distribution. It's not  surprising that you don't hear any difference between the unstressed vowel in "happy" and the vowel in "bee": the sounds are well known to be merged in perception for many speakers. The different names of Wells's lexical sets are intended to facilate discussions that deal with multiple dialects: they don't constitute an assertion that all of the sets are distinct in all dialects.

Comment: @1006a: In fact, neither of the dialects that Wells intended to account for with his original sets ("General American" and "Received Pronunciation") distinguish all of the sets from one another. For example, the three sets LOT, CLOTH and THOUGHT correspond to only two vowel phonemes in either dialect: three "diaphonemic" categories are needed to explain the distribution of these sounds when talking about both dialects (in GA, CLOTH = THOUGHT while in RP, CLOTH = LOT) but there is no three-way distinction.

Comment: @sumelic Yes, I didn't mean to suggest there was no point to having the distinction in the set; just that part of the reason for my confusion was because, in my dialect, the vowel intended by HAPPY was already accounted for by FLEECE, so when I was reading through and expecting a new vowel to be introduced by HAPPY my first thought was the first vowel (actually TRAP or BATH, apparently). The new note as-written doesn't really clear up that potential point of confusion, since it's still written from the perspective of speakers who can readily distinguish between FLEECE and HAPPY.

Comment: @1006a That's why Wells made his "it seemed like a good idea at the time" comment. For speakers like you and me, they're the same vowel.But for many other speakers the vowel in the second syllable of *happy* is the same vowel that they use in the word *kit*, not the vowel they use in the word *fleece*. For speakers like you and me, the differnce is phonetic, not phonemic - the vowel in *happy* is theoretically shorter than the vowel in the word *fleece* - but it's the same vowel.

Comment: @Araucaria [Most North American English dialects merge the lax vowels with the tense vowels before /r/.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English-language_vowel_changes_before_historic_/r/#Mirror%E2%80%93nearer_merger) That explains why we don’t think of *nearer* as having the KIT vowel but rather the FLEECE vowel. See also the *mirror–nearer* merger.

Comment: @tchrist Ah, yes. That would explain it. I learn something new on here every day!

Comment: I have another question about /ie/. I have just observed words like tenacious and cautious. Why do they have transcriptions like /ʃəs/ instead of /iə/. These mean that they have one syllable(ə) different from the words can count as two syllables (/iə/)  , and -ious can be /iə/ and /ə/?

Answer (score 5):

It might make it easier to answer your question if you gave more information about what context in which you need to know these symbols (are you more interested in being able to read dictionary transcriptions correctly, or in being able to make your own transcriptions that will be considered "correct" by somebody else?). The short answer to "How different are they pronounced?" is "not very": being able to distinguish something like /iə/ from something like /ɪə/ is not an essential feature of a native-sounding English accent. If they are distinguished, it will likely be by syllable count, as Araucaria suggests: /iə/ in a modern transcription is likely to represent two vowels pronounced in two separate syllables.

The symbol /ɪə/ is often used as a fairly conservative phonemic transcription of a British English vowel sound that was traditionally described as a tautosyllabic falling centering diphthong (thus, a more explicit transcription of the traditional phonetic realization would be [ɪə̯], with the non-syllabic diacritic on the schwa). Words that were pronounced with [ɪə̯] in RP may be pronounced instead in many present-day British accents with a phonetic monophthong [ɪː]. In addition to [ɪː], some speakers may use in certain contexts a pronunciation like [ɪjə] that sounds like it has two syllables, with a vowel like the one in the word "fleece" (the FLEECE vowel) in the first and a vowel like the one in the second syllable of "comma" or "letter" in the second, and a gliding transition between them.

Because of this, it seems to be disputed whether the inventory of contemporary standard British English speakers should be analyzed as containing a tautosyllabic diphthong phoneme /ɪə/: it may be the case that we can analyze some speakers as instead having a phonemic inventory containing the long monophthong /ɪː/, the FLEECE vowel /ɪj/, and schwa /ə/ where a sequence of the FLEECE phoneme and the schwa phoneme can be phonetically realized as [ɪə] or [ɪː] instead of as [ɪjə] because of optional processes of compression. (Variation in speaker intuitions about syllable count doesn't only exist for British English speakers: American English speakers have similar variation in how many syllables they assign to words like *foil* and *snarl*).

### Longer Discussion

#### The use of the IPA length marker <ː> in phonemic transcriptions

Some transcription systems for English do not make of the IPA letter <ɪ>. Purely "quantitative" transcriptions use /iː/ for the sound found in *knee* or *fleece,* and /i/ for the sound found in *kit.* You can see an overview of some different transcription systems in this post by John Wells: [IPA transcription systems for English](http://www.phon.ucl.ac.uk/home/wells/ipa-english-uni.htm).

When you are looking at a transcription in a dictionary, you can find out if it uses a purely quantitative or a quantitative-qualitative system by looking at the key, or at the transcriptions used for words that you already know how to pronounce.

When you are making your own transcriptions, I would not recommend using a purely quantitative transcription, as they don't seem to be popular currently.

Wells favors a quantitative-qualitative system, and these seem to be pretty popular. But an important point to remember is that **the use of the length marker in quantitative or qualitative-quantitative phonemic transcription systems for English is completely unrelated to the non-phonemic processes that affect phonetic vowel length** in English based on stress and what type of consonants follow the vowel. The word "seat" is pronounced with a phonetically shorter vowel than the word "seed", but in a quantitative or qualitative-quantitative phonemic transcription, both are transcribed with the phoneme /iː/ with a length marker: /siːt/, /siːd/.

Also, you can't necessarily assume that a phonemically "long" vowel will be realized with greater phonetic length than a phonemically "short" vowel: for example, if I remember correctly, the low vowel /æ/, although phonemically classified as a "lax" or "short" vowel and therefore not marked with a length marker in phonemic transcriptions, tends to be realized as fairly long phonetically.

Because of the potential for confusion between phonemic and phonetic length—concepts which it is essential that an EFl learner distinguish—some phoneticians such as Jack Windsor Lewis prefer to avoid using length markers in phonemic transcriptions (see [The Undesirability of length marks in EFL phonemic transcription (1975)](http://www.yek.me.uk/undesire.html)).

#### The traditional RP "near" diphthong is /ɪə/ (in one syllable)

The symbol /ɪə/ is traditionally used to transcribe a vowel phoneme identified as the vowel in the word "near". Historically, this originates from a "long e" sound (which in other contexts became the vowel phoneme often transcribed /iː/) that became "colored" by the following *r*. In accents that have lost word-final *r* as a consonant, like standard British English, the remnant of this "coloring" is the reason *near* sounds different from *knee,* even though neither ends in a consonant sound.

In "Received Pronunciation" (RP), the "near" vowel is considered to only take up a single syllable, but to move from one vowel sound to another; it is therefore categorized as a diphthong, like /aɪ/ or /aʊ/. The monophthongal vowel thought to sound most similar to the first element of the RP "near" vowel is /ɪ/, as in "kit", while the monophthongal vowel thought to sound most similar to the final element of the RP "near" vowel is /ə/, as in the last syllable of "comma" or "letter". Thus, the typical transcription of the RP "near" diphthong is /ɪə/. Of course, in a purely quantitative transcription system where the "kit" vowel is written as /i/ and the "fleece" vowel is written as /iː/, the *near* vowel would be written /iə/ rather than /ɪə/.

#### /ɪə/ or /iə/ is also used for sounds that didn't originate as r-colored "long e"

As Araucaria's answer mentions, the symbols /ɪə/ and /iə/ do not only correspond to the reflex of "r-colored long e" (as I describe it) in British English.

The other main source is original sequences of two vowels in hiatus (you can usually tell from the spelling, which will involve two "vowel letters" like *ia* or *ea*). In contemporary accents, these may be pronounced in two syllables or one, depending on certain factors like stress, morphological structure, and perhaps frequency (in that more learned, less frequent words may be more likely to be pronounced with two syllables), and there is a fair amount of variation.

When there is no stress on the vowel written "ɪ" or "i", it can often be replaced with a non-syllabic glide /j/, resulting in /jə/.

When there is stress on the first vowel and it is pronounced in a separate syllable from the following "ə", it is usually written with a length marker (assuming we are using quantitative or quantitative-qualitative transcription), so you would typically see /iːə/ (or, with the syllable divisions explicitly marked, /iː.ə/).

#### Variation: monophthongization, dieresis and smoothing

Geoff Lindsey's blog post "[The demise of ɪə as in NEAR](http://englishspeechservices.com/blog/the-demise-of-%C9%AA%C9%99-as-in-near/)" presents a case against using the concept of a tautosyllabic diphthong "ɪə" in descriptions of "contemporary Standard Southern British" accents. He writes:

> In the earlier standard/reference accent of British English, Received Pronunciation, words like NEAR contained a centring diphthong, **ɪə**. This was a vowel which glided from the lax quality **ɪ** to the quality **ə** within a single syllable. It can be heard in this clip from a 1930s Pathé documentary about beef and *beer*: [audio clip removed]
>
> Such a vowel is heard relatively rarely today. Although British dictionaries still use “/ɪə/” in their transcriptions, a lax diphthong of this type is now rather old-fashioned.
>   In contemporary Standard Southern British (SSB), we hear tend to hear
>   either
>
> 1. a long pure vowel, the monophthong ɪː; or
> 2. a form in  which the tense FLEECE vowel is followed by schwa, which we could write as ɪjə or, with traditional symbols, as /iːə/; this form can
>      plausibly be considered to comprise two syllables.

[...]

> In SSB, NEAR is commonly ɪjə or ɪː. Some speakers use both; for them, NEAR may be considered varisyllabic, like WIRE and SOUR. Others seem to use only ɪː. Either way, the transcription of NEAR as a monosyllabic lax diphthong “/ɪə/” is now rather out of date.

More blog post about the phonetics of the "near" vowel and related sounds:

- "[Smoothing, then and now](http://englishspeechservices.com/blog/smoothing-then-and-now/)" (Geoff Lindsey)
- "[rising diphthongs](http://phonetic-blog.blogspot.com/2012/10/rising-diphthongs.html)" (John Wells)
- "[diphthong, schmiphthong](http://phonetic-blog.blogspot.com/2009/11/diphthong-schmiphthong.html)" (John Wells)
- "[Smoothing and Compression](http://www.yek.me.uk/archive41.html#blog406)" (Jack Windsor Lewis)

The Wells "rising diphthongs" post has this interesting bit at the end:

> Inspired by Jones’s pair *reindeer — windier*, another phonetician (I think it was Bjørn Stålharne Andrésen, but I can’t lay my hands on the reference, so this is from memory) performed a listening experiment in which he got speakers to imagine that as well as *reindeer* and *roedeer* we also have a kind of deer called a *windeer*; he asked them to pronounce in suitable carrier sentences the words *windeer* (kind of deer, with its falling diphthong in the second syllable) and *windier* (more windy, with its putative rising diphthong), and then played the results to listeners who were asked to decide which of the two words had been said. They proved unable to do this with better than random success. So the distinction between NEAR (my **ɪə**) and happY plus schwa (my **i‿ə**) may indeed be ‘felt subjectively by the speaker in slow utterance’, but the hearer cannot reliably detect it.